# Cross drag behavior for game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to create a block game where you can drag blocks. I'm looking for the friendliest drag behavior. It should only move horizontal or vertical, and 1 block position only. It should snap (ease to desired target position), cause you cannot release it in the middle (in between blocks). It should kinda behave like an iPhone switch button, but in a cross. I have tried to do it by check the angle of the mouse to the original position of the block, to check which direction it should move. I want it always to go move through the center (original position). I mean; it cannot animate from the left position to the upper position, it should animate to the center first.

The blocks are top-left aligned and there is spacing between the blocks.

What is the best way to do this? 
[image: Drag behavior game example]

**UPDATE:**
This is my current code. It currently moves into upon the direction, but doesn't animate to the point.

```
package nl.stroep.games.behaviors 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import nl.stroep.games.boxgame.Setting;
    /**
     * Target dragging behavior
     * @author Mark Knol
     */
    public class CrossDragBehavior 
    {
        private static const HALF_PI:Number = Math.PI / 2;
        private static const QUART_PI:Number = HALF_PI / 2;

        private var _target:DisplayObject;
        private var _targetPosition:Point;

        public function CrossDragBehavior(target:DisplayObject) 
        {
            _target = target;

            _target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouse);
            _target.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouse);
        }

        private function handleMouse(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            switch(e.type)
            {
                case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN:
                {
                    _targetPosition = new Point(_target.x, _target.y);
                    _target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
                    update(null);
                    break;
                }
                case MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP:
                {
                    _target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private function update(e:Event):void 
        {
            var mouseX:Number = _target.parent.mouseX;
            var mouseY:Number = _target.parent.mouseY;

            var dx:Number = mouseX - _targetPosition.x;
            var dy:Number = mouseY - _targetPosition.y;
            var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

            //trace(angle);

            var directionX:int = 0;
            var directionY:int = 0;

            if (dx * dx + dy * dy > Setting.BLOCK_WIDTH * Setting.BLOCK_WIDTH) // minimum distance before snap
            {
                if (angle < 0 * HALF_PI - QUART_PI) { directionX = 0; directionY = -1; }
                else if (angle < 1 * HALF_PI - QUART_PI) { directionX = 1; directionY = 0; }
                else if (angle < 2 * HALF_PI - QUART_PI) { directionX = 0; directionY = 1; }
                else if (angle < 3 * HALF_PI - QUART_PI) { directionX = -1; directionY = 0; }
                else { directionX = 1; directionY = 0; }
            }

            _target.x = _targetPosition.x + (directionX * (Setting.BLOCK_WIDTH + Setting.BLOCK_DISTANCE))
            _target.y = _targetPosition.y + (directionY * (Setting.BLOCK_HEIGHT + Setting.BLOCK_DISTANCE))
        }

        public function set target(value:DisplayObject):void 
        {
            _target = value;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably something you may have to find out by yourself.

As in any application, start simply, break down your problem into chunks, try to identify problematic issues, then implement a first structure, flexible enough to be improved upon.

I don't understand every aspect of your game...

```
  "cause you cannot release it in the middle" //middle of what, of the cross?
  "I want it always to go move to the center." // how's that possible?
  "It should only move horizontal or vertical, and 1 block position only"
  "It should kinda behave like an iPhone switch button, but in a cross"
```

Personally, I find all these lines confusing. How can it be in a cross, if it's only moving by one block?

Setting aside these issues , you could start by creating a Block class.

What does it need to do?

```
- Move Up   
- Move Down   
- Move Left   
- Move Right
```

here you have the choice to implement a single method or a method per movement. Your choice :)

If you know where the Block goes then it's easy to make it snap. With a tweening method, you simply need a destination point, a delay and an ease function to make it move smoothly.

Directions are not too difficult too, in a mouse move you can easily compute the direction, when you have the direction, you have the destination. If you have the destination , you have the method.

So to sum up, some of the properties & methods your Block class may have...

```
  private var left:int = 0;
  private var right:int = 1;
  private var top:int = 2;
  private var down:int = 3;

  private var tweenDelay:Number = .5;

  // event listeners
  private function mouseDownListener(event:MouseEvent):void{};
  private function mouseUpListener(event:MouseEvent):void{};
  private function mouseMoveListener(event:MouseEvent):void{};

  //get a couple of coordinates, feed them to the method & 
  //return an int (or a String )
  private function getDirection(params:Object):int;

  private function tweenBlock( direction:String ):void{}
```

Throw a few Booleans in to limit the movements of your Block, or use a Rectangle not to go out of bounds. Voila! :)

I've probably forgot or overlooked some stuff but this should get you started.

On the other hand, if you already know all of the above and are stuck, please tell us exactly what the issue is and it may be possible to be more helpful.

Comment: Sorry, this is because of my English. These 2 answers matter:

"cause you cannot release it in the middle" 
You should not be able to release it in between two blocks, it should snap to one of the blocks.
'

Comment: "I want it always to go move to the center." 
It should always go across the original position. This is the actual problem. If I drag the block to the left (for example), then my target position  is the left block. It should move to the left. But when I don't release the mouse and move/drag the block like it should go UP, the block should not move up, because you should move your mouse the the right (to go back to the center) and than you could drag it up.